# Swift 3 convert unicode string U+1F600

Tags: ios, json, swift, unicode

so I'm trying to convert a unicode string `U+1F600` coming from json into a UILabel but having a hell of a time.

Has anybody encountered this?  It also seems JSON coming in as `\u1f600` has the same issues.

I've tried this method with no luck:
[Emoji characters cannot be encoded to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177808/emoji-characters-cannot-be-encoded-to-json)

Thanks so much

Comment: `U+1F600` and `\u1f600` are not valid as JSON. Can you show what byte sequence you have received?

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32555223/1630618

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks vacawama and Edmar, both helped me find the solution which was as follows:

```
if let unicode = definition["unicode"] as? String {
    if let int = Int(unicode.replacingOccurrences(of: "U+", with: ""), radix: 16) {
        if let scalar = UnicodeScalar(int) {
            let string = String(scalar)
            emoji.text = string
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON response, does `\u1f600` comes in a string format ? If so, try this:

```
let transform = "Any-Hex/Java"
let input = "\\u1f600" as NSString
var output = input.mutableCopy() as NSMutableString

CFStringTransform(output, nil, transform as NSString, 1)

println("output: \(output)")
```